# How to do a distinct select with CountRows in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, powerpivot

I want to do a distinct select on the field `Object_name` with the below measure ,how would that be possible in excel ?

```
=countrows(filter(GDPR,GDPR[Object_Type]="Table"))
```

Comment: Not clear : You want distinct rows of a table ? Or of cells ?

Comment: distinct rows of a table ,like for example you have two objects with the same name ,I want only the latest to be returned

Answer (score 0):

You may find an explanation for each formula in the links below,
where "data" stands for the range of cells or their columns.

[**Count unique values in a range with COUNTIF**](https://exceljet.net/formula/count-unique-values-in-a-range-with-countif) :

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(data,data))
```

[**Count unique numeric values in a range**](https://exceljet.net/formula/count-unique-numeric-values-in-a-range) :

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(data,data)>0))
```

[**Count unique text values in a range**](https://exceljet.net/formula/count-unique-text-values-in-a-range) :

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(FREQUENCY(MATCH(data,data,0),ROW(data)-ROW(data.firstcell)+1)>0))
```